# Remove everything from a string but numbers, dots and single letters with preg_replace

Tags: php

How to modify this code to remove **everything from a given string exept** *numbers* (already there) **AND** *strings*: ".", "k ", "B ", and "M "?

What Im doing is parsing prices given in: 123k, 124.7B, 20M

```
preg_replace("/\D/", "", "<td>Cost: 20b $, Sell for: 139k $</td>" );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick (as defined in question):

```
preg_replace("/[^\.kBM0-9]/", "", "<td>Cost: 20b $, Sell for: 139k $</td>" );
```

I think a preg_match may be better, especially if there is more than one number in your string (as in your example):

```
preg_match_all("/([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\s?[kBM]?)/", "<td>Cost: 20b $, Sell for: 139k $</td>", $match );
```

All numbers should then be nicely separated in the `$match` array.